# Image processing: High pass filter to remove lowest 16 frequencies

Tags: image-processing, fft, filters, fourier-transform, python

How can I remove the lowest n frequencies of an image? Are the lower frequencies around the centre of the FFT result?

Comment: I would say the lower left corner is the DC. You can test by creating a 2D sine signal and run the FFT.

Comment: Let's say I use fftshift to put the DC component in the centre. How could I select exactly n frequencies? Can I just use a circular mask on the FFT result to remove the lowest n frequencies? But how to I adjust the radius?

Comment: In the 2D FFT, every point represents a 1D wave with a direct according to point, a frequency according to the distance from the origin, and a phase based on your reference position on the wave. Now, the mask you want to use, do it around the origin. Why you need the shifting?